# How to merge 2 columns in an Excel sheet using axlsx gem in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, axlsx

```
sheet.add_row['Heading', '', 'Value']
sheet.add_row['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
```

Say I have the above 2 lines of code to write data to a spreadsheet using axlsx gem. There are 3 columns for which I have added data as shown above. However I would like to merge row1:col1 and row1:col2 ('Heading' and '').

I have used this code and this works:

```
sheet.merge_cells "A1:B1"
```

However, I would like to merge the 2 cells in the current row dynamically without having to hardcode the cell positions like A1 & B1.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question can be found in [axlsx RubyDocs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/axlsx/2.0.1/Axlsx/Worksheet#merge_cells-instance_method) for `merge_cells` method

```
worksheet.merge_cells "C1:E1"
# you can also provide an array of cells to be merged
worksheet.merge_cells worksheet.rows.first.cells[(2..4)]
```

Comment: I am adding several hundreds of rows using `sheet.add_row[]` function. And based on some condition, I woud like columns A and B to be merged ONLY for the current row which is getting added by my most recent `add_row` call. How do I achieve that?

`worksheet.rows.first.cells[(2..4)]` merges C1:E1 and not columns C till E of the current/most recent row in the spreadsheet.

Comment: `add_row` returns `Row` object, so you can use `cells`method to access cells you are interested it. For future please refer to [documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/axlsx/2.0.1/Axlsx/Worksheet#add_row-instance_method)